# How to parse out a <td> from html with regex

Tags: c#, regex

Here is the part I'm trying to parse.

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td>Network</td>
    <td>Vodafone Uk Ltd</td>
</tr>
```

I'm trying to only get this part parsed

```
<td>Vodafone Uk Ltd</td>
```

I've tried stuff like this `<td>(*?)</td>` but I've had no luck so far.

Comment: You only want Protected and not Network? Why? What is the criteria?

Comment: I've updated my main post, it's to show which network the person is using.

Comment: There's no `<td>Protected</td>` in your input now..

Comment: Sorry updated once again it's not the protected I'm trying to parse exactly but it's the second td value

Comment: So, you want the contents of the `<td>` directly after `<td>Network</td>`, or what?

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Comment: This is sounding more and more like you do want to use the HTML Agility Pack, as suggested by @PimBrouwers in an answer (which should be a comment) below.

Answer (score 0):

If you're parsing HTML in C#, I would recommend using [HTML Agility Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

```
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load("http://somepath.com"); //use this to load from url
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html); //use this to load from string
HtmlNode docNode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode; //bring DocumentNode into Context
var allTDs = docNode.SelectNodes("//td");
```

Comment: Okay thanks for the information but I've never used HTML Agility Pack before is there any questions already answered in relation to what I'm looking for but in HTML Agility Pack. I've tried looking but can't find much on this here.